# Sharepoint 2010 Blog Creation

Tags: sharepoint, blogs

I am using sharepoint 2010. And I want to create blog site, but i cant. Which feature activation provides me to create blogs? Thanks

Comment: Since this question isn't programming related, you can ask it on [SharePoint.SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter which SharePoint *(2007, 2010 / Server, WSS or Foundation)* you use creating a Blog site demands one simple thing, the rights to create a Site.

Ensure your user is listed in the owners group and you'll be alright

Comment: I can create nearly everything but not blog. And I am also in owners group.

Comment: A SP Blog is a Site Template, this might be broken in such case.